# Is Klebsiella pneumoniae found in the throat of healthy people?

Tags: bacteriology, microbiome

Is [*Klebsiella pneumoniae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klebsiella_pneumoniae) found in the throat of healthy people?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For example, reading and linking to the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klebsiella_pneumoniae) and (if this is true) indicating that you were specifically interested in the throat and why knowing it is in the normal oral microbiome isn't sufficient. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Klebsiella* species, including *pneumoniae*, are normal members of the healthy human **oral** microbiome.

[***Klebsiella* and *Providencia* emerge as lone survivors following long-term starvation of oral microbiota**](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1820594116)

Saliva microbiomes from 6 healthy adults were analyzed by 16S sequencing over a starvation timecourse, where oral microbes were cultured in minimal medium (PBS or 1:1 PBS:cell-free saliva).  [Figure 1](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/116/17/8499/F1.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1) shows that the genus *Klebsiella* is initially low abundance in the healthy oral microbiome, but the proportion of *Klebsiella* increases over the starvation timecourse in the two media tested.  An excerpt from the results:

> At day 1, several species of *Streptococcus* were recovered, as were *Gamella sanguinis*, *Klebsiella pneumoniae*, and *Klebsiella oxytoca*. At day 20, *K. pneumoniae*, *K. oxytoca*, *Enterobacter homaechei*, and *Providencia alcalifaciens* were the only recoverable species. Finally, at day 84 and day 100, only *K. pneumoniae* and *P. alcalifaciens* were recoverable under the conditions tested

Given the proximity of the mouth to the throat, I think it's fair to say that *K. pneumoniae* is likely a member of the healthy human throat.

If that's not convincing, you can check the supplemental data from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0066476), which looked at 16S data associated with **throat** tissue samples from 29 patients with laryngeal carcinoma and 31 control patients with vocal cord polyps.  Looking at the relative abundance of different phyla, they found that Proteobacteria (the phylum containing the genus *Klebsiella*) accounts for 11% of the recovered 16S reads on average for all patients (range 0–67.1%).  The authors claim to have recovered 218 genera and >3000 unique [OTUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_taxonomic_unit) at 97% similarity, though they only report the ~30 most abundant genera in their differential abundance analyses, and it doesn't look like they included the full dataset in this publication.